# Stop sections from being cut off when xps file is created on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xps, xpsdocument

**The Application**

I am working on an EHR application. The page I am working on converts the contents of a `XAML` file's data to an `XPS` file which can be printed or drawn on. When the page's data in on the `XAML` page it can easily be scrolled through and the data is kept inside a `BlockUIContainer`. *However* once the `XPS` file is generated, some sections are cut off.

**Application Code**

Inside the 10-14YearVisit form XAML file

```
<!--History Section-->
      <BlockUIContainer>
        <genForms_Controls:PatientHistoryUC />
      </BlockUIContainer>
<!--History Bottom-->
```

The PatientHistoryUC.xaml (Sorry, lots of code!)

```
<UserControl x:Class="Pcis.Emr.GeneralForms.Controls.PatientHistoryUC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:genForms_Controls="clr-namespace:Pcis.Emr.GeneralForms.Controls"
             xmlns:galenControls="clr-namespace:Pcis.Emr.GeneralForms.Galen.Controls"
             xmlns:util="clr-namespace:Pcis.Emr.Common.Utils;assembly=Pcis.Emr.Common"
             xmlns:sectionDatas="clr-namespace:Pcis.Emr.Data.SectionDatas;assembly=Pcis.Emr.Data"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
  <Border BorderBrush="Black"
          BorderThickness="1"
          CornerRadius="5"
          Width="790"
          Margin="0,0,2,5">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <!--past medical history-->
      <galenControls:GalenPastMedicalHistory Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                             util:FormTemplateSectionUtil.ShowInForm="{x:Static sectionDatas:SectionType.ProblemList}"
                                             util:FormTemplateSectionUtil.TemplateId="{Binding TemplateId}"
                                             Margin="3"/>
      <genForms_Controls:ProblemsSection PMHFontSize="11"
                                         Margin="3"
                                         Grid.Row="1"
                                         Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                         util:FormTemplateSectionUtil.ShowInForm="{x:Static sectionDatas:SectionType.Problems}"
                                         util:FormTemplateSectionUtil.TemplateId="{Binding TemplateId}" />
      <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                  Margin="3">
        <!--past surgical history-->
        <Button Grid.Column="0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Style="{StaticResource NoBorderButtonHand}"
                Command="{Binding PickPSHCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
          <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     FontWeight="Bold"
                     Text="Past Surgical History"
                     TextDecorations="Underline"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     Foreground="Blue" />
        </Button>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0"
                      Margin="0,0,6,0"
                      ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource PSHItemTemplate}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding PastSurgicalHistoryChronicOnly, Mode=Default}"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" />
      </StackPanel>
      <StackPanel x:Name="FH_SH"
                  Grid.Column="4"
                  Grid.Row="2"
                  Margin="3"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <!--Family history-->
        <galenControls:GalenFamilyHistory />

        <genForms_Controls:SocialHistoryUCTreeView />
        <Grid>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
      </StackPanel>
      <StackPanel x:Name="PMH_PSH"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Grid.Row="2"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Width="390.423"
                  Margin="3">
        <Grid Margin="0,5,0,0"
              Grid.Row="1">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.799*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.201*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <!--current medications-->
          <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                      Orientation="Horizontal"                      
                      Margin="0,0,8,0"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                      Width="249" />
        </Grid>
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
  </Border>
</UserControl>
```

xps file generation

```
    public bool SaveDocument(
    out string path,
    out string error,
    bool digitallySign = true,
    SerializerWriterCollator customCollator = null,
    PageRange? pr = null,
    string headerText = null,
    bool printAccount = true,
    HorizontalAlignment patientAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    HorizontalAlignment headerTextAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
    HorizontalAlignment logoAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
    int headerFontSize = 13,
    Typeface headerTypeFace = null,
    string generatedNote = null,
    bool alwaysThrow = false)
    {
      path = Util.GetTempFile("xps");
      error = string.Empty;

      SerializerWriterCollator collator;
      XpsDocument doc = null;
      bool endBatchWrite = false;

      if (customCollator != null)
      {
        collator = customCollator;
      }
      else
      {
        doc = new XpsDocument(path, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
        collator = writer.CreateVisualsCollator();
        collator.BeginBatchWrite();
      }

      int count = 1;
      int flowDocumentCount = 0;

      foreach (FlowDocument flowdoc in this.Documents)
      {
        if (pr != null && pr.Value.PageTo != 0 && (count < pr.Value.PageFrom || count > pr.Value.PageTo))
        {
          continue;
        }

        IDocumentPaginatorSource source = flowdoc;
        DocumentPaginator p = source.DocumentPaginator;

        p.PageSize = new Size(this.extentWidth, this.extentHeight);
        p.ComputePageCount();
        this.TotalPages += p.PageCount;

        flowDocumentCount += p.PageCount;
      }

      int currentPage = 1;

      foreach (FlowDocument flowdoc in this.Documents)
      {
        IDocumentPaginatorSource source = flowdoc;
        DocumentPaginator p = source.DocumentPaginator;

        p.PageSize = new Size(this.extentWidth, this.extentHeight);
        p.ComputePageCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < p.PageCount; ++i)
        {
          DocumentPage page = p.GetPage(i);
          ContainerVisual v = new ContainerVisual();
          DrawingVisual header = this.CreateHeader(
            currentPage++,
            this.TotalPages,
            digitallySign,
            headerText,
            printAccount,
            patientAlignment,
            headerTextAlignment,
            logoAlignment,
            headerFontSize,
            headerTypeFace);

          ContainerVisual cv = new ContainerVisual();
          cv.Children.Add(page.Visual);

          // This offset is how far down the header will show.  If the logo cuts off, it's because
          // it extends below the Y variable in the line of code below in the new Vector(x,y)
          cv.Offset = new Vector(0, 45);
          v.Children.Add(cv);

          v.Children.Add(header);

          v.Transform = new ScaleTransform(0.96, 1);
          v.Offset = new Vector(24, 0);
          collator.Write(v);
          endBatchWrite = true;

          Util.LogAccess("Printing a Document", AccessLogComponent.HealthRecord, AccessLogAction.Print);
        }
      }

      if (customCollator == null)
      {
        if (endBatchWrite == true)
        {
          collator.EndBatchWrite();
        }

        doc.Close();
      }

      // Minus on from the current page due to the fact that we start on page 1.
      return this.HandleCreationError(currentPage - 1, flowDocumentCount, path, generatedNote, alwaysThrow, out error);
    }
```

**Example of Before and After:** (All of the patient data is made up)

**Pre-XPS**
[image: PreXPS]

**XPS**

[image: XAML file]

**PatientHistoryUC.xaml Layout**
[image: Layout]

**What I want to happen**

Depending on the amount of data being supplied to the `XPS` generated file, pagination occurs which moves excess contents to the next page rather than cutting off. I believe the `BlockUIContainer` is the main issue as it can't be split into two when the data becomes too much for the set page size (8 x 11).

Thank you for reading.

Comment: How are you generating the XPS file - can you show this code please?

Comment: Added the xps file generation function